# What is the difference between True and msoTrue in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a model with some VBA code that hides/shows shapes:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("shape1").Visible = msoTrue`

A previous developer used msoTrue throughout the model instead of True which is what I have typically used in this type of application.

I am trying to understand the difference between True and msoTrue, and wonder if I should be using one or the other. I know that both equal -1.

Comment: This is rather broad - also, what [have you searched for?](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+True+and+msoTrue+in+VBA%3F)

Answer (score 1):

`msoTrue` is a constant that evaluates to -1. In VBA it would be a `Long` type.

`True` is a `Boolean` type. When converted to a `Long` it also evaluates to -1.

Try this:

```
Debug.Print msoTrue '---> -1
Debug.Print True '---> True
Debug.Print Clng(True) '---> -1
```

It is somewhat odd to use `msoTrue` instead of `True` in a condition test, but -1, `msoTrue` and `True` will all be a true condition.

I should add that the `Visibility` property of the `Shape` object isn't a `Boolean` type, it's a `Long` of the enum `msoTriState`. If your question relates specifically, and only, to `Shapes`, then, yes, the more correct syntax would be `msoTrue`.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!